# Where Clause on Compound Index Produces "not indexed" Error

Tags: dexie

I have the following table schema:

```
db.version(1).stores({
    sales: "[item_id+date],sales"
});
```

Where the combination of `date` and `item_id` must be unique. How can I get all the records for a given `item_id` using the `where` clause (disregarding the date)?

The following produces an error:

```
db.sales.where('item_id').equals(some_item_id)
```

> Unhandled rejection: SchemaError: KeyPath item_id on object store sales
>   is not indexed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.sales.where('[item_id+date]').between ([some_item_id, -Infinity], [some_item_id, Dexie.maxKey])
```

Comment: Thanks you. For some reason the above returns `n-1` records. Perhaps it is because `between` is non-inclusive?

Comment: OK, `between ([some_item_id, -Infinity], [some_item_id, Dexie.maxKey, true, true)` does it.

Comment: This just doesn't seem to work, I have executed the following query, `await window.db.Thread.where('[last_message_received_timestamp+needSync]').between([Dexie.minKey, 1], [Dexie.maxKey, 1]).toArray()` and it returns me the entire set of results. I have verified that there is not value in IDB with needSync = 1. I am using Chrome Latest version

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Dexie.minKey and Dexie.MaxKey must be the second position of the array. You put it in the first.'